# Displaying Table has no Columns using Google Charts

Tags: java, json, spring, google-visualization

Trying to change the format of JSON to make it readable for Google charts. 
The JSON content is working fine and currently displaying this on the browser:

```
[["name","cost"],["godzilla",12],["harry potter",12]]
```

The Task is being performed by a spring controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "api/productschart", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public @ResponseBody
    String listProductsJsonChart () throws JSONException {

    JSONArray ProductArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray ProductHeader = new JSONArray();

    ProductHeader.put("id");
    ProductHeader.put("cost");

    ProductArray.put(ProductHeader);


    for (Product product : productRepository.findAll()) {
        JSONArray ProductJSON = new JSONArray();

        ProductJSON.put(product.getId());
        ProductJSON.put(product.getCost());

        ProductArray.put(ProductJSON);
    }
    return ProductArray.toString();
}
```

The JavaScript section

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

  var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8081/api/productschart",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
  }).responseText;


  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);



  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data);
}
</script>
```

Comment: JSON strings are *always* double-quoted.

Comment: so how can I make any changes to make it readable for google charts?

Comment: Google Charts supports JSON, so it has to be double quotes. Your problem must be elsewhere. What error message do you get?

Comment: table has no columns @AaronDigulla. I am trying to implement a simple column chart https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Answer (score 1):

The examples on Google's pages use single quotes because they use JavaScript to build objects and JavaScript supports both single and double quotes. JSON, on the other hand, requires double quotes.

> table has no columns

From the example at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Data_Format, I think your JSON should look like this:

```
[["id","cost"],["1",12]]
```

i.e. the first item in the data part of the array needs to be a string. In your case, it's a number.

Comment: I replace the attribute. Now the output is   [["name","cost"],["godzilla",12],["harry potter",12]] but still showing table has no columns

Comment: Have a look inside of `jsonData` on the client. Log it to the console. Is that a long string or is it an array?

Comment: used google chrome's javascript console. its stating that     **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**. Is that the error?

Comment: @HarshVardhan: Quite likely. This means some URL is wrong. In the network or resource tab, you should be able to see which one.